# Установка wxWidgets для CodeLite

Tags: wxwidgets

Следуя [инструкции](http://codelite.org/Developers/BuildingWxWidgetsWin) завис на пункте

```
Open the file \path\to\wxwidgets\lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx\setup.h
```

вся проблема в том, что директория gcc_dll отсутствует

Пытался собрать, но и там при сборке по инструкции выбило кучу ошибок

При самой попытке сборки в CodeLite получаю

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C mingw32-make.exe -j 2 -e -f  Makefile
----------Building project:[ test - Debug ]----------

Please use the --prefix flag (as in wx-config --prefix=C:/wxWidgets)
or set the environment variable WXWIN (as in WXWIN=C:/wxWidgets)
to specify where is your installation of wxWidgets.

Please use the --prefix flag (as in wx-config --prefix=C:/wxWidgets)
or set the environment variable WXWIN (as in WXWIN=C:/wxWidgets)
to specify where is your installation of wxWidgets.

Please use the --prefix flag (as in wx-config --prefix=C:/wxWidgets)
or set the environment variable WXWIN (as in WXWIN=C:/wxWidgets)
to specify where is your installation of wxWidgets.
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Ni55aN/Documents/codeLite/test'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o.d] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
test.mk:99: recipe for target 'Debug/main.cpp.o.d' failed
```

ОС: Win10 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeLite требует, чтобы исходники wxWidgets находились строго по пути `C:\wxWidgets`
(пока не знаю, как изменить путь)

В общем положил исходники, скачанный отдельно архив с gcc_dll распаковал, также в `CMAKE_LDFLAGS` указав `wx-config --wxcfg=gcc_dll/mswud` все собралось

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы CodeLite перестал ругать Вас за отсутствие gcc_dll/mswud, Вам всего лишь необходимо после "установки" WxWidgets, например в `C:\WxWidgets\`, закинуть в переводчик текст файла `README.md` (открывать лучше в Notepad++ или подобных ему, которые выстраивают текст "правильно") и прочитать в подразделе "Building(Сборка)", что неплохо было бы детально ознакомиться еще и с содержимым `install.md`, который лежит в `C:\WxWidgets\docs\Ваш_вариант:gtk,msw osx\`, и согласно инструкции "собрать" комплект просимого CodeLite.

у меня были установлены MinGW + CodeLite, поэтому я выполнил в CMD.exe следующее:

```
cd C:\WxWidgets\build\msw
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc**
```

и подождал минут 30 пока все соберется, перезагрузил комп и готово!

п.с. **простите меня грешного за этот возмутительный акт гробокопательства**, однако иначе поисковик Яндекса так и будет выдавать этот пост среди релевантных, а решение, как вы уже убедились, несколько иное..

Comment: свое возмущение оставляйте при себе. Тем более, вопросу, как и решению, уже 5 лет, и вероятно вы просто ошиблись вопросом